# Convert C# object to GET request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to convert my C# object to GET request. Though i did it manually in my controller post method but i was just wondering, is there any way to convert c# object to GET request.

e.g: I created my endPointURI string in my controller manually but i want to do that through some systematic process.

I have a class named ClassA that looks like this

ClassA

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a form in my View using this class that looks like this

Search.cshtml

```
<div>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchAction", "Search", new AjaxOptions()
        {
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "ResultBox"
        }))
 {

        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Origin:</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Origin, new { @class = "form-control" })<br/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Destination:</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Destination, new { @class = "form-control"})<br/>
        </div>

        <div class="text-center">
          <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Check" />
        </div>
}
```

and my action "SearchAction" in controller class "SearchController" is like this

SearchController.cs

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SearchAction()
    {
        return View();
    } 

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SearchAction(ClassA obj)
    {
        // I want to make this string through some process ( not manually)
        String endPointURI = "/v1/shop?origin="+obj.Origin+"&destination="+obj.Destination;
        return View("Result",endPointURI);
    }
```

Comment: If it's specific to that object you could override ToString in your object to return the query string. If you really want to develop some sort of convention-based approach where your query string is in the format objectpropertyname=ObjectPropertyValue, you could use reflection.

Comment: A bit like @dgavian said, it would be way simpler to make 2 functions, on that translate all the info into a string, and one that retreive all the info of that string, into classA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely looking for [`UriHelper.Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx)

Code would look approximately:

```
 String endPointURI = Uri.Action(
     actionName:"shop", controllerName:"ShopController", 
     routeValues: new {origin=obj.Origin,destination=obj.Destination});
 return View("Result",endPointURI);
```

Note that if action you are trying to redirect to takes whole `ClassA` as argument you can pass it directly.

```
 ActionResult Shop(ClassA model)...

 Uri.Action(... routeValues: new {model=obj});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but i think that there is no way to do it automatically. Maybe you can use String.Format to make it easier: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx